# Silverlight toolkit. StackedColumnSeries Remove column borders

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

Cannot find where i can change in StackedColumnSeries column style. I need to remove borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Resource file your project:

```
<ResouceDictionary>
<Style x:Key="style name">
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
```

And

```
 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```

Legend effect

```
SeriesDefinition.DataPointStyle = (Style)App.current.Resources["style name"];
Style name:uniq
```